# Can I get current route information in middleware with Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I need to have the current found controller and action in a middleware, so that I can do some authentication. But I found it impossible, because the pipe is like Middleware1 -> Middleware2-> do the dispatching -> controller@action() -> Middleware2 -> Middleware1.

Therefore before the dispatching, I cannot get the route info. It is definitely not right to do it after the $controller->action().

I did some research and found this.

```
$allRoutes = $this->app->getRoutes();
$method = \Request::getMethod();
$pathInfo = \Request::getPathInfo();
$currentRoute = $allRoutes[$method.$pathInfo]['action']['uses'];
```

But this does not work when visiting URI like `app/role/1`, because `$allRoutes` only have index of `app/role/{id}` instead of `app/role/1`.

Is there any workaround about this?

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: @peterm I need to get the matched route info including controller name, action name, in the middleware before the action is invoked.

Comment: I have pulled request to Lumen 5.0 and waiting to be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct answer to this problem. I missed one method named `routeMiddleware()` of `Application`. This method registers the route-specific middleware which is invoked after dispatching. So Just use `$app->routeMiddleware()` to register you middleware. And get the matched route info by `$request->route()` in your middleware.

Comment: Could you explain more please, because I don't understand how to get the current route

Answer (score 6):

After do some research, I got solution. Here they go:

#### Create Custom Dispatcher

First, you have to make your own custom dispatcher, mine is:

```
App\Dispatcher\GroupCountBased
```

Stored as:

```
app/Dispatcher/GroupCountBased.php
```

Here's the content of `GroupCountBased`:

```
<?php namespace App\Dispatcher;

use FastRoute\Dispatcher\GroupCountBased as BaseGroupCountBased;

class GroupCountBased extends BaseGroupCountBased
{
    public $current;

    protected function dispatchVariableRoute($routeData, $uri) {
        foreach ($routeData as $data) {
            if (!preg_match($data['regex'], $uri, $matches)) continue;

            list($handler, $varNames) = $data['routeMap'][count($matches)];

            $vars = [];
            $i = 0;

            foreach ($varNames as $varName) {
                $vars[$varName] = $matches[++$i];
            }

            // HERE WE SET OUR CURRENT ROUTE INFORMATION
            $this->current = [
                'handler' => $handler,
                'args' => $vars,
            ];

            return [self::FOUND, $handler, $vars];
        }

        return [self::NOT_FOUND];
    }
}
```

#### Register Your Custom Dispatcher in Laravel Container

Then, **register your own custom dispatcher** via `singleton()` method. Do this **after** you register all your routes! In my case, I add custom dispatcher in `bootstrap/app.php` after this line:

```
require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/routes.php';
```

This is what it looks like:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/routes.php';

// REGISTER YOUR CUSTOM DISPATCHER IN LARAVEL CONTAINER VIA SINGLETON METHOD
$app->singleton('dispatcher', function () use ($app) {
    return FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function ($r) use ($app) {
        foreach ($app->getRoutes() as $route) {
            $r->addRoute($route['method'], $route['uri'], $route['action']);
        }
    }, [
        'dispatcher' => 'App\\Dispatcher\\GroupCountBased',
    ]);
});

// SET YOUR CUSTOM DISPATCHER IN APPLICATION CONTEXT
$app->setDispatcher($app['dispatcher']);
```

#### Call In Middleware (UPDATE)

> **NOTE**: I understand it's not elegant, since `dispatch` called after middleware executed, you must dispatch your dispatcher manually.

In your middleware, inside your `handle` method, do this:

```
app('dispatcher')->dispatch($request->getMethod(), $request->getPathInfo());
```

Example:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    app('dispatcher')->dispatch($request->getMethod(), $request->getPathInfo());
    dd(app('dispatcher')->current);
    return $next($request);
}
```

#### Usage

To get your current route:

```
app('dispatcher')->current;
```

[image: PoC]

Comment: I have not tried this, but it looks great. I think it should work. I will update this soon.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. Please check this [src code](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Application.php#L1091). The middlewares are invoked before dispatching. So the `$current` in Dispatcher is always null, unless the invoking order is changed.

Comment: This does get the current route. However, in your sulution the dispatching happened twice, see [here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Application.php#L1097). Thanks anyway.

Comment: As I've said, it's not elegant way, because dispatch will called twice. To avoid this, you may change dispatch method in Application. Check whether dispatcher has been dispatched or not, if not, do dispatch and vice versa.

Comment: I pulled request about this. [here](https://github.com/silentred/lumen-framework/commit/bad3c665f6592fee58ff1b9707d72f3e74fb9568)

Answer (score 1):

```
$methodName = $request->getMethod();
$pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
$route = app()->router->getRoutes()[$methodName . $pathInfo]['action']['uses'];
$classNameAndAction = class_basename($route);
$className = explode('@', $classNameAndAction)[0];
```

Comment: This solution is failed when you pass dynamic parameters in URL. eg. `GET/api/visited-profiles/{recordsPerPage}/{pageIndex}`. Any suggestion?