# How to get the current route on middleware in lumen framework?

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, middleware, lumen

I have develop the API application using lumen. And for the access permission control. I want to get the current route in middleware. But, I always get null on:

```
   $route = $request->route();
```

I already try the way on the [Can I get current route information in middleware with Lumen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577949/can-i-get-current-route-information-in-middleware-with-lumen) which using the routeMiddleware and  dispatcher. But it's still return null. How could I get the current route on middleware?

Thank a lot..

Answer (score 6):

Please update your Lumen... Everything works with no issues

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $route = $request->route();
    $path = $request->getPathInfo();

    // your code here
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Note that `->route()` will be `null` unless you're using a _named_ route.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible. At least it's not as simple as calling `getCurrentRoute()`.

You need to go through routes collection and match them again with request path.

Take a look at this rough example: https://gist.github.com/radmen/92200c62b633320b98a8

Please note that some parts of this code may not work ;) I've extracted this code from my app (slightly different use case) and tried to fit it to your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
maybe this

$request   = new \Illuminate\Http\Request;
$method    = $request->getMethod();
$pathInfo  = app()->getPathInfo();
$routeName = app()->getRoutes()[$method.$pathInfo]['action']['as'];
```

Comment: An explanation of what every line does would have been helpful

Answer (score 1):

There is a more elegant way of doing this.

Extend the Application class if you have not already and add this extra method:

```
use Laravel\Lumen\Application;

class YourApplication extends Application
{
    /** override other methods if needed */

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentRoute()
    {
        return $this->currentRoute;
    }
```

}

Then you can access it in your Middleware like this:

```
$route = app()->getCurrentRoute();
$action = $route[1];
$info = $action['uses']; // string(57) "YourApp\Http\Controller\Public\UserController@view"
```

Comment: `currentRoute` is only set after all the global middlewares are applied. And only then you have the value set for the variable. https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/7f1672b8a6d7f14c72029d56d21672c815723c10/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php#L168-L176 And if that's the case, then you can just use `app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class)->getRouteResolver()()` to serve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

From the Laravel docs:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#basic-request-information

> The path method returns the request's URI. So, if the incoming request is targeted at http://domain.com/foo/bar, the path method will return foo/bar:

```
$uri = $request->path();
```

There are even other methods you may find helpful:

```
if ($request->is('admin/*')) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: this was specifically a lumen question NOT a laravel question

Comment: @BillGarrison Lumen is based off of laravel. This should work for laravel.

Answer (score 0):

in global middleware, you can not get route from request directly, but you can get if in a routeMiddleware.

so, just use `routeMiddleware`, and in middleware, `$request->route()`.

if you just want to get it in a global middleware, just clone the $request, and set a dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

Not actually. Lumen is using a totally different router and NOT native laravel router. So it is not the same. Although lumen was based on laravel, some (or should I say almost 60% of the engine was different. Including the router app, which uses Nikic/fastroute....

Comment: This is a better comment on the topic than a solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$uri = $request->path();
```

From the Lumen docs:
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RouteNameMiddleware
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $request->attributes->set('currentRouteName', array_search($request->getPathInfo(), app()->router->namedRoutes));

        // your code here
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then you can access your attributes in Controller / Blade View

```
app('request')->get('currentRouteName')
```